# Test rows while reading compressed file with data.table::fread

Tags: r, data.table, bioinformatics, fread

I am writing a function to parse outputs specific to a software (`bismark stranded_CpG_report`) :

```
21      13      +       0       0       CG      CGA
21      14      -       0       0       CG      CGA
21      100     +       0       0       CG      CGT
21      101     -       0       1       CG      CGC
21      150     +       2       0       CG      CGG
```

Because these files are huge I need to filter out lines with `0` in the 4th and 5th columns.

Now the only way I know how to achieve it is by calling shell command :

```
fread(cmd=paste("zcat -f ", "path/to/file.tsv" ," | awk '$4 || $5'"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I have two questions :

- Is there another way to test rows while reading with `fread` than calling shell commands? Like built-in functions that would work on both Unix & Windows.
- Calling the `awk` command without `zcat` doesn't work with compressed file, is there a reason why ? It worked well without the `cmd` parameter.

Thanks for your help

Comment: 1 is a [long-standing feature request](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/583). Implementation is quite difficult to do well, I think `awk` is pretty well suited for your case. Could you elaborate on point 2? I don't follow completely

Comment: Without extensive personal experience, `vroom::vroom` alleges to have this efficiency built-in: `dat <- vroom(myfile); dat <- dat[ dat[,4] | dat[,5], ]` is supposed to *not* read all data from other columns (immediately). That is, it finds the location of all field separators, and then only retrieves *data* on-demand, and only from rows/columns intended. With the above sample, I "believe" that it will have to read all of columns 4-5, but from there it should only need to read the matching rows.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelChirico.On point 2  `fread(cmd= "awk '$4 || $5' ", "path/to/file.tsv.gz" )` doesn't seems to uncompressed the file and produce an error.
@r2evans Thanks I never heard of this package before I will check

Comment: oh, well `awk` is not built to handle compressed input... `zcat` is the perfect tool for that AIUI

Comment: *"is there a reason why"* that `awk` doesn't deal with compressed files? My belief is that it is among the unix "2-3 letter" tools (with the PDP-8 and PDP-11 in mind :-). where they are designed with orthogonality in mind. That is, a tool does only a few things, but does them well and fast. If you need more "things" done at once, pipe them together, so the possible combinations of "compressed" and "data" and other things we only limited by the `|` pipes you could contrive. Embedded compression handling in cli tools (except `tar`) is relatively recent.

Comment: aah got it. I was thinking wrong, I thought fread would first decompressed and then apply the `awk` command.

Comment: nope, all the command-line stuff happens first; its output is written to a temporary file, then `fread` applied to that